# Odata service call not working in Cordova SAPUI5 Application?

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I have a working SAPUI5 application, I have migrated the SAPUI5 application to Android application using Cordova. After creating the cordova application and importing it into Android Studio,I have copied the required files from webcontent (index.html,Component.js,View, Controller, util) and pasted them into Cordova project www folder. Now when running the Android studio project(Cordova application) build has been successfully created and it is running in emulator.
The only issue is that odata service call is not happening in the app. I have removed the proxy (proxy/http/****) and declared http (http://***), but the service call is not working. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Anything else you know from this failed call? Do you know the returned HTTP status code, for example?

Comment: I have the same error and I don't get any error log when I run my app